# How to make cells in data table editable onclick specific row using Quasar?

Tags: quasar-framework

I am using [data table](http://quasar-framework.org/components/datatable.html) component in Quasar. I am able to view table and it’s awesome. here's

Now I need to click on a row cell and make it editable input text field, and after pressing ‘Enter’ button I need to save data there itself.
How to proceed further? please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is I didn't find any inbuilt functionalities of the data table to edit row. So I thought of moving with my custom functionalities. The good thing about Data table in Quasar is that it provides the use of templates for manipulation of any row.

So I used a template like this:

```
<template slot="col-Name" scope="cell">
            <span @click = "nameAction()">{{cell.data}}</span>
            <input type="text"
               v-model="cell.data" v-show="edit1" v-on:keyup.enter="edit1 = false;"> <br>
         </template>
```

So here I'm cosidering one of the row in the column(Name), and on click of the row calling a function called **nameAction**. 
And here is the function inside a method:

```
nameAction: function (row) {
  this.edit1 = true
}
```

Here I am making an input field visible on clicking the row.
For reference, you can use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yobyzal/gehtwxeo/).